# Visual C++ API for Network Monitoring

Tags: visual-c++, network-programming

I have to make a network monitoring application, under Visual C++ (Windows)
What libraries or APIs do you recommend me to use?

Comment: And what do you want to monitor? What datasources? What protocols?

Answer (score 2):

[Transport Driver Interface (TDI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Driver_Interface) filters allow you to monitor network traffic.

You could also try using [libpcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) which powers ethereal/wireshark.  This is based on [Network Driver Interface Specification (NDIS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NDIS).

Answer (score 1):

Few options, depending on what you really want to monitor:

- Net-SNMP (or other SNMP library) for talking with the network equipment and getting the data from various MIBs (**for example you want to collect interface counters, cpu utilization, and other goodies provided by the vendors**)
- WinPcap for doing more low-level, packet oriented things (**for example capture certain types of traffic using the power and speed of BPF filters**)
- If you are interested in collecting specific type of information (NetFlow, sFlow) then I cannot help you much. There are ready tools but I'm not sure if there is any in form of a library.
- RRDtool (**If you want to show the user some nice plots**)